# Hadoop multiple input zipped files processing

Tags: hadoop

I have a folder consisting of around 20Lakhs zipped input files. Each zipped file consists of 2 to 4 files. I have a MapR cluster of size 5.
i am using hadoop MapReduce to process these files. I want to combine N number of input files at a time before processing it in the mapper. 
Any suggestions on how can i combine some input files to get multiple files processed by a single mapper?

Comment: Do you have these input files in s3? and what form for zipped files you have? gzip, zip or something else ?

Comment: it is a .zip file and I have it in the MapR File System

Comment: See if this article helps: http://www.bigdataspeak.com/2013/01/how-to-combine-input-files-to-get-to_11.html . I am sure it works for uncompressed files and also I am sure it doesn't work for .gzip files. Hope it works for .zip files.